# Django: icontains over unicode string

Tags: python, django, unicode, django-models

My client is asking something very weird but that makes sense in everyday operations.

I have an user with the first name Nicolás and I am filtering through first name with the value Nicolas.

Is there a way to show up the results?
Thanks!

The code I have so far

```
    q = request.GET['q']

    q_res = Member.objects.filter(
        Q(first_name__icontains = q)|
        Q(last_name__icontains = q)
    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`unaccent`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/postgres/lookups/#unaccent), to make accent insensitive queries. This only works with postgres, and on Django 1.8+ I believe.

If this isn't applicable to you, then you can't do this directly. One potential alternative is to store an unaccented version of the string in a new field and search by that. There's a [`library`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Unidecode) for getting the closest possible regular string from a unicode one.